# Google Map KML layer - click event return ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am working with the Google Maps KML layer click event.

I am using this code:

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://sites.google.com/site/anoopkml123/kml/ab9Plan0520.kmz');

  ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    alert(kmlEvent.featureData.name);
  });
}
```

Sometimes `alert(kmlEvent.featureData.name)` shows a number but sometimes it's 'undefined'.
Sometimes `obj.featuredData.id` is null (ZERO_RESULTS status is in status field).

Comment: Sudha: So, what behaviour do you expect?

Comment: Is this for clicks on the [Polygons](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/SO_ab9Plan0520.kmz)?  I have seen similar reports, don't know of any work around or responses.

Comment: This is hard to answer without more details - does it return data when you click on your shapes only, and not otherwise? Is there a repeatable way to get it to return data and not return data? Also would posting a screenshot help? How about posting a jsfiddle?

I took a *quick* look at the KML and it seems in order.

Answer (score 1):

Re-created your code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mdares/TAfys/

I cannot replicate the issue you are having. Can you provide an example given the above link of where it fails? Is this possibly browser specific? Finally - is there any additional code you haven't posted which might be the cause? My code is unchanged from yours as you posted, but I am curious if you are also doing other things:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.875696, -87.624207),
    zoom: 11,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('https://sites.google.com/site/anoopkml123/kml/ab9Plan0520.kmz');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'click', function (kmlEvent) {
    alert(kmlEvent.featureData.name);
   });
}
```

Comment: I have had similar issues to the original post - the problem is  not consistently reproducible, sometimes clicks work and sometimes they don't.

Comment: Similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084561/kml-layer-not-working-properly-google-maps-api