# KML layer does not always respond to clicks [ Google Maps API ]

Tags: google-maps, maps, kml

I am working on a project .jsp file, that displays 4 kml layers: gas pipes, gas sensors, valves, and areas.

The problem is that I want to extract data from the placemark's description and use it, but when I click the placemark, sometimes it works, other it doesn't. And I simply can't see why..

I have created a JSFiddle example of my code. I've added 2 kml layers, one for pipes and one for sensors. Each pipe has multiple sensors( or at least one). I added the layers one after the other on metadata change to be sure of layer order consistency. I added 2 click listeners for both layers that extract the description and I process the string and extract what I need, to display in a separate div as text.

Sometimes when I click the sensors or pipes the data is extracted, other times it says it's not found(string undefined). I get the status = "ZERO_RESULTS". According to Google, this may occur if the geocoder was passed a latlng in a remote location. I looked at the log and the latlog has more than 9 numbers after the dot(.), wheras in my kml I only have 6.

But this isn't the problem i guess because sometimes, although the latlng coord are very accurate,( >9 chars after the dot) the placemark is found and the info I need is extracted. It's just hit or miss.

Can someone explain to my why this is happening?

JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/sxNy9/185/light/

KML files:
 - https://sites.google.com/site/kmlholdersherb/BrasovLayer_TeziGaz.kml?attredirects=0&d=1
 - https://sites.google.com/site/kmlholdersherb/BrasovLayer_Senzori.kml?attredirects=0&d=1

Thanks!

EDITED:

Included the kml layers:

```html
var PIPES= new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'URL HERE', preserveViewport:true});

var SENSORS= new google.maps.KmlLayer({url: 'URL HERE', preserveViewport:true });
```

After that I added them to the map.

And now the listeners.

```html
google.maps.event.addListener(SENSORS, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
    var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
    var str = kmlEvent.featureData.description;

    //FIND OUT THE STREET
    var x = str.indexOf(".");
    var y = str.indexOf(":");
    var street= str.substring(y+2,x); 

    //ID
    var a = str.indexOf("#");
    var ID = str.substring(a+1,str.length);

    var finaltext = street+ " " + ID;

    showInContentWindow(finaltext); // adding the string into html ( aka the result)
});
```

And then another listener for PIPES, which is identical.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself, not links to off site pages.  A jsfiddle is a useful supplement, but doesn't replace _your_ (relevant) code in the question itself.

Comment: So is the .jsp file any good? Because the problem is not in that file. But I can post it you want. But the project is huge.. And the relevant stuff is in the fjiddle link.(or at leas that concerns my part).

Comment: All you really need to do is add code from the fiddle to your question (which is what the message you received when tried to add a link to a fiddle, but it wouldn't let you, tried to tell you). I don't have time to do that for you.

Comment: On your fiddle I see this status on the "FeatureData" property of the event in the click listener `status: "ZERO_RESULTS"` after leaving the page open for a while, seems like there is a request back to the google server when the click event happens that has expired, and doesn't return any results.  However, this "status" on the KmlFeatureData of the KmlMouseEvent, doesn't seem to be documented...

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I thought. I also did allot of digging around and with no success.. Hope I can do something to prevent this 'expiring'.

Comment: I have been having similar issues - sometimes clicking on kml works, and sometimes it doesn't...
I have tidied up the original JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hh6n0j51/